# Google API - Translate a string into EN language :(

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I am trying to make a simple web based application which will translate a non-english (non-EN) string into English (EN) language. For this I am using Google's Translation API (v1- JS).

At first I am detecting the language provided in a div tag (note that page encoding is set to UTF-8).

Then I am trying to translate the text if it is in non EN language and then it is to be displayed just below the detected language tag.

I am able to obtain the language detected but the translation never happens! :(

Any help would be much appreciated..

Here's the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script
    src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=mykeyfrxwexdfwezfdhfxcewx" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     *  How to detect the language of text.
     */


    google.load("language", "1");

    function initialize() {
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        // Setting the text in the div.
        content.innerHTML = '<div id="text">Hola, me alegro mucho de verte.<\/div><div id="detected"><\/div><div id="transtext"/>';

        // Grabbing the text to translate
        var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

        // Detect the language of the text.
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
            var detected = document.getElementById("detected");
            // If there wasn't an error in the request
            if (!result.error) {
                var langCode = result.language;
                var langName;

                // Loop through the languages enum so that we can find the actual name of the language.
                // Learn about the languages enum here:
                // http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/reference.html#LangNameArray
                for ( var i in google.language.Languages) {
                    var thisLangCode = google.language.Languages[i];
                    if (thisLangCode == langCode) {
                        // find the language code, store the language name.
                        langName = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // See the detected language.
                detected.innerHTML = 'Detected: "' + result.language
                        + '" - aka "' + langName + '"';
            }
        });

        google.language.translate(text, 'es', 'en', function(result) {
            var translated = document.getElementById("transtext");
            if (result.transtext) {
                translated.innerHTML = result.transtext;
            }
        });

    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
    <div id="content">Loading...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am able to detect the language but I am not able to see the translated text. I am not able to guess what's wrong with this code. No error(s) crop up. :( ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 points to note .

You are not actually calling translate within the callback of detect.
The translate result does not contain a property transtext . The one you need is named translation .
I doubt you want to post your API key in a public domain

Find modified code below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script
    src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     *  How to detect the language of text.
     */


    google.load("language", "1");

    function initialize() {
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        // Setting the text in the div.
        content.innerHTML = '<div id="text">Hola, me alegro mucho de verte.<\/div><div id="detected"><\/div><div id="transtext"/>';

        // Grabbing the text to translate
        var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

        // Detect the language of the text.
        google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
            var detected = document.getElementById("detected");
            // If there wasn't an error in the request
            if (!result.error) {
                var langCode = result.language;
                var langName;

                // Loop through the languages enum so that we can find the actual name of the language.
                // Learn about the languages enum here:
                // http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/reference.html#LangNameArray
                for ( var i in google.language.Languages) {
                    var thisLangCode = google.language.Languages[i];
                    if (thisLangCode == langCode) {
                        // find the language code, store the language name.
                        langName = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // See the detected language.
                detected.innerHTML = 'Detected: "' + result.language
                        + '" - aka "' + langName + '"';
            google.language.translate(text, result.language, 'en', function(result) {
            var translated = document.getElementById("transtext");
            if (result.translation) {
                translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
            }

        });

            }
        });


    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
    <div id="content">Loading...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx for the suggestion :) but still I am not able to run it successfully. Infact, the language detection does not work anymore :( As far as the API is concerned, it is from Google help. :)

Comment: you substituted your api key in the code i posted ? I replaced it with xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: @echo9 , re-reading your original comments , I feel you didnt actually read my comments , just copied and pasted the code and tried to run it . There was enough info in the original comments to know whats wrong with the code and correct it . Me posting the corrected code was an unnecessary step.

Comment: Now I have to make it flexible i.e processing user entered strings instead of hard coded "Hola!.." :)